# JQuery get a copy of table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am stuck in cloning html part of table row (TR) inside my div rest my code works fine but not copying table rows html data
here is my jQuery code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('<div/>', {
         'class' : 'extraPart', html: GetHtml()
     }).appendTo('#container');
     $('#addRow').click(function () {
           $('<div/>', {
               'class' : 'extraPart', html: GetHtml()
     }).hide().appendTo('#container').slideDown('fast');
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');  
     });
 })
 function GetHtml()
{
      var len = $('.extraPart').length;
    var $html = $('.extraPartTemplate').clone();

    $html.find('[name=txtvehicle]')[0].name="txtvehicle" + len;
    $html.find('[name=txtcolor]')[0].name="txtcolor" + len;
    $html.find('[name=txtengine]')[0].name="txtengine" + len;
    $html.find('[name=txtchassis]')[0].name="txtchassis" + len;
    $html.find('[name=txtcost]')[0].name="txtcost" + len;
    $html.find('[name=txtselling]')[0].name="txtselling" + len;
    $html.find('[name=txtrlcheck]')[0].name="txtrlcheck" + len;
    $html.find('[name=txtbranches]')[0].name="txtbranches" + len;

    $html.find('.bootstrap-select').replaceWith(function() { return $('select', this); });
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
return $html.html();
}
```

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/258rpq68/

Comment: Welcome to the community . and also can you make a fiddle?, without the html it is kinda hard to infer detail

Comment: You should return clone element i.e. `return $html;`

Comment: Can I just make a suggestion, write out the full name for `len`, you don't save anything making it `var len` compared to `var length`, you gain readability though.

Comment: Where is the HTML?

Comment: Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/258rpq68/

Comment: You could take a minute or two to clean out the php? I can add the jquery reference for you

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/258rpq68/3/

Comment: updated and clean php here you go https://jsfiddle.net/258rpq68/6/